Why do Compton scattering plots all exhibit $(1 - cos\theta)$ shape?
I continue to study the formula for Compton scattering.
From Compton wavelength formula Eq.1, we can express $E_f$ in terms of $E_i$ as:
$$
E_f = \frac{E_i}{1+\frac{E_i}{m_e c^2}(1-cos\theta)} \tag{7}
$$
Since the kinetic energy of the electron particle $KE_e = E_i - E_f$, its ratio to $E_i$ stands for the efficiency of photon energy transfer to electron K.E.:
$$
\frac{KE_e}{E_i} =\frac{E_i - E_f}{E_i} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{m_e c^2}{E_i(1-cos\theta)}} \tag{8}
$$
From Eq.4, we have:
$$
1 +\frac{p_i - p_f}{m_e c} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{v}{c})^2}}
$$
Therefore, the electron velocity can be derived as:
$$
(\frac{v}{c})^2 = 1-(\frac{1}{1 +\frac{p_i - p_f}{m_e c}})^2 = 1-\{{\frac{1}{1 +\frac{1}{(\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_c} ) [1+ (\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_c} )(\frac{1}{1-\cos\theta})]}}}\}^2\tag{9}
$$
where ($\lambda_i, p_i, E_i$) and ($\lambda_f, p_f, E_f$) are photon's wavelength, momentum and energy, respectively, before and after scattering.
Common to Eqs. 4, 8 and 9 is the $(1-cos\theta)$ factor.
The following are 4 plots for Eqs. 1, 8, 9 and (2, 3 or 6) as a function of $\theta$ for 3 different $\lambda_{{in}}$: 0.5 nm (2.5 Kev), 0.1 nm (12.4 Kev) and 0.02 nm (62 Kev), which covers the Compton experiment's 17 Kev.

The first figure for $\lambda_{{out}}$ has been normalized by $\lambda_{{in}}$. The first 3 plots fit the $(1-cos\theta)$ curve as suggested in their respective equations.

I just wonder if they are all actually just one Compton equation?

They all peak at $180^\circ$. Is that because the photon
momentum/wavelength changes the most, thus the electron gains the most
of energy transfer?

Also, the energy transfer efficiency favors higher energy X-ray or lower $\lambda_{{in}}$, why?



Isn't (1) obvious? Particle velocity is just the square root of particle KE. Wavelength of light is directly connected with energy too. (2) is correct. (3) is obvious from your Equation (8), where $E_i$ is in the denominator. If that is bigger, then the effect is stronger.

Thanks for the confirmation. Particle KE is a relativistic kinetic energy. Equation (9) shows $(\frac{v}{c})^2 = 1-(\frac{1}{1 +\frac{KE}{m_e c^2}})^2$. The Taylor expansion of $KE \approx \frac{1}{2}mv^2[1+\frac{3}{4}(\frac{v}{c})^2+\frac{5}{8}(\frac{v}{c})^4]$. The derivative of $\frac{dKE}{dv}=mv[1+\frac{3}{2}(\frac{v}{c})^2+\frac{15}{8}(\frac{v}{c})^4]$ shows that KE increases rapidly as $\frac{v}{c}$->1 Fig.3. This is shown in the subplot 3 where the electron velocity flattens as $E_i$ and KE increase.
